# Ruby case statement does not perform as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fyi, using Rails.

Given `user = User.find(1)`

This case statement returns `nil` when it should return the result of `self.do_something_with_user`.

```
def case_method
    case self.class
      when User
        self.do_something_with_user # assume does not return nil
      when SomeOtherClass
        self.do_something_else
      else
        nil
    end
end

user.case_method # => nil
```

What am I missing?  Using pry, `self.class == User` returns true.

Comment: What does `do_something_with_user` return? Is it possible that it returns `nil`? Try debug printing to determine exactly which branch gets executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's `case` statement is much more flexible than most other `switch` statements. It uses the `===` operator, not the `==` operator. Classes define the `===` operator along the lines of

def ===(other)
    other.is_a? self #self is the class
  end

So, what you actually want here is:

```
def case_method
  case self
  when User
   do_something_with_user
  when SomeOtherClass
    do_something_else
  end # else is un-needed as it will return nil by default
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's `case` uses `===` (the [case equality operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Statement.htm)) to check equality.

While `0.class == Fixnum` results in true, `0.class === Fixnum` results in false.